# Short way to convert string to int

Tags: python, type-conversion

I usually do this to convert string to int:

```
my_input = int(my_input)
```

but I was wondering if there was a less clumsy way, because it feels kind of long.

Comment: I can't imagine what a shorter version is supposed to look like, even in principle. Unless you want to rename `i = int` or something? But we have to use some kind of code (calling a function is as short as it gets), and we have to assign the value back (because strings are immutable).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
my_input = int(my_input)
```

There is no shorter way than using the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) function (as you mention)

Comment: int('88.8') will report error

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you were hoping for something like `my_number = my_input.to_int`. But it is not currently possible to do it natively.  And funny enough, if you want to extract the integer part from a float-like string, you have to convert to `float` first, and then to `int`. Or else you get `ValueError: invalid literal for int()`.

**The robust way:**

```
my_input = int(float(my_input))
```

**For example:**

```
>>> nb = "88.8"
>>> int(nb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '88.8'
>>> int(float(nb))
88
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is user input, chances are the user inputted a string. So better catch the exception as well with `try`:

```
user_input = '88.8'
try:
    user_input = int(float(user_input))
except:
    user_input = 0
print(user_input)
```