# python 3.6 turn part of string into variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code here.
    equation = "4x+7"
And I would like to make the 4 and 7 into integers and define x as an integer so I can work out y for the equation. Any easy solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short way to convert string to int Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837247/short-way-to-convert-string-to-int-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

```
number1 = 4
number2 = 7
x = 1
```

Then use it:

```
number1 * x + number2
```