# How to convert String to Int, in List of Tuples?

Tags: python

My list is like this and following is my code but it does not work.

```
 templist = [('375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'), ('CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0')]
 for i in range(len(tempList)):
     tempList[i][1] = int(float(tempList[i][1]))
     tempList[i][2] = int(float(tempList[i][2]))
     tempList[i][3] = int(float(tempList[i][3]))
```

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question. See also [ask] and [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short way to convert string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837247/short-way-to-convert-string-to-int)

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension with unpacking:

```
[(s, *map(float, fs)) for s, *fs in templist]
```

Output:

```
[('375ml Bott 24', 6.0, 10.0, 60.0), ('CHINA WINE', 4.0, 16.0, 64.0)]
```

Explanation:

- `for s, *fs in ...`: for the elements of tuples in `templist`, take first item (`str`) as `s` and **rest** as `fs`.
- `(s, *map(float, fs))`: keep the first item as it is, and convert `fs` into `float` then unpacking into a new tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change a tuple but you can't since it is immutable. What you can do instead is convert to a list, change the values and convert back to a tuple:

```
templist = [('375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'), ('CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0')]

for i,tup in enumerate(templist):
     l = list(tup)
     l[1] = int(float(l[1]))
     l[2] = int(float(l[2]))
     l[3] = int(float(l[3]))
     templist[i] = tuple(l)

print(templist)
```

Output:

```
[('375ml Bott 24', 6, 10, 60), ('CHINA WINE', 4, 16, 64)]
```

You could also use a list comprehension to do the same:

```
for i,tup in enumerate(templist):
     l = list(tup)
     l[1:] = [int(float(x)) for x in l[1:]]
     templist[i] = tuple(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
tempList = [['375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'], ['CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0']]
for i in range(len(tempList)):
    tempList[i][1] = int(float(tempList[i][1]))
    tempList[i][2] = int(float(tempList[i][2]))
    tempList[i][3] = int(float(tempList[i][3]))
print(tempList)
```

Comment: the list type cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of tuples. Elements of a list can be changed, it can have different tuple but tuple is immutable. you should have list of lists as mentioned below :

```
tempList = [['375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'], ['CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0']]


In this case :
templist = [('375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'), ('CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0')]

tempList[0] = tempList[1] # can be done because it edit the list which is mutable
tempList[0][1] = tempList[1][1] # can't be done because it edit the tuple which is immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:
Convert the Tuple inside the List into Lists and convert string to Float.

```
templist = [('375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'), ('CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0')]
result =[]
for i in range(len(templist)):
    lis=list(templist[i])
    lis[1] = float(lis[1])
    lis[2] = float(lis[2])
    lis[3] = float(lis[3])
    result.append(lis)
print(result)
```

Your new list is **result**

Answer (score 0):

We cant change the type inside a tuple but we can create a new tuple based on the old templist. Try this:

```
templist = [('375ml Bott 24', '6.0', '10.0', '60.0'), ('CHINA WINE', '4.0', '16.0', '64.0')]
newlist = []
for item in templist:
    z = []
    for i in item:
        try:
            z.append(int(float(i)))
        except:
            z.append(i)
    newlist.append(tuple(z))

print(newlist)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('375ml Bott 24', 6, 10, 60), ('CHINA WINE', 4, 16, 64)]
```